# ASP createobject does not work on server 2012 R2

Tags: object, asp-classic

what works on Serrver 2003 does not work on 2012.

I register a DLL with regsvr32, and get a positive result. The IUSR has the right to read and execute the dll-file. The IIS allows the page to run scripts.

But in classic ASP, when I try server.createobject, I get "ActiveX cannot create object".

I know there is a similar question, but i know the registration was positive.

Brgds
Peter

Comment: Could you add some code?  If you're using a 32 bit component and you havent enabled 32 bit applications in your app pool then you need to do this.

Comment: Additionally to what John has said, if it is a 32 bit DLL, make sure you register it to the syswow64 folder instead of the system32 folder.